# Have you seen this extension property?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

I'm looking for a reference for the following extension property:
A functor $F: C \to D $ such that for any arrow $f: x \to y$ in $C$ there is an extension $f = \hat{f} \circ i$ with $i:x \hookrightarrow z$ monic and $F\hat{f}$ an isomorphism in $D$.

My motivation is that if $D$ is an ordinal category then this is a really simple (and restrictive) definition of dimension that fits other needs of my research.

**EDIT:** Expanding on the dimension part: the point to use this as a definition of dimension has several advantages:

1. The dimension of pullbacks/pushouts acts as expected.
2. There are no morphisms from a higher dimension object to a lower dimension one.

This means that the dimension property is, in some sense, external to the underlying categorial structure.
If we view this dimension structure as geometrical - it helps separate geometric constructions from the underlying building blocks of the construction - the category itself (this also creates difficulties modeling this dimension functor in concrete cases, but that is a technical issue in my point of view).

The last point can be extended further: The existence of such functor can be used to restrict the behavior of the morphisms related to this "external structure" (for ordinal $D$ this is point 2). The extension property is there to connect the "external structure" to the underlying category, but in a very controlled way. Now, dimension is not necessarily the only thing we want to control.

For example we can take $D=\alpha\times E$ with the first coordinate meaning dimension, and the second a discrete category - this is for any invariant under existence of morphisms (say Euler characteristic). The existence of a functor, both restricts what morphisms are allowed - only increasing the dimension and preserving some strong invariant. Every morphism can be studied as an embedding into the $D$-isomorphism class of it's codomain.

Comment: You don't usually ask for a solution to a lifting problem to belong to a certain class of maps (those $f$'s inverted by $F$ are called $F$-local maps); instead, you ask it to the "sides" of the square. This to say that I've never seen this before (but I'll gladly learn something new!)

Comment: Ah, another clarification in case I have something more to say: is it enough for you to consider $D$ an ordinal? This is a great simplification!

Comment: @FoscoLoregian Well, right now ordinals is all I need. But, hypothetically you could replace this ordinal with a different category encoding both dimension and Euler characteristic of the space, or any other interesting invariants you want. So this might be of interest to explore different categories as well

Comment: A few things: 1. What does it mean for pullbacks to behave "as expected"? 2. What is the significance of the extension property? Point (2) follows simply from the existence of a functor $F: C \to D$ and point (1) follows simply from $F$ preserving pushouts (though I'm confused about pullbacks). 3. What's an example? For instance, consider the category of sets and all functions $X \to Y$ where $|X| \leq |Y|$. Then the $Ord$-valued functor $F(X) = max(|X|^+,\aleph_0)$ preserves pushouts (but not pullbacks) and has the extension property. Is this the sort of thing you have in mind?

Comment: @TimCampion To answer points 1 and 2: If we look at pullbacks in an over category, then they correspond to intersection. With this intuition, if we look at every object as a subobject of object of higher dimension (the extension property is this exactly) - the dimension of "intersection" of subobjects is $\leq$ the dimension of the objects. The extension property is there to make this intuition rigorous

Comment: @TimCampion 3. Your example is indeed a natural manifestation of the extension property. In fact, most examples should look similar - a category with "dimension" that behaves well with subobjects (rank of a group is an anti-example) - say vector spaces, or $R$-Modules, or anything with the word `Noetherian` in its name. Take any such category and remove all morphisms from a higher dimensional object to a lower dimensional one and you get a subcategory satisfying the property.

Comment: In fact I'm starting to reconsider this formulation, and instead talk about a class of monomorphisms that all have images, and a functor from this category. This way you don't need to restrict the morphisms from the category you usually work with (Until now I did not find an example not satisfying this which is not contrived) and actually talk about subobjects directly (and there is a dual of the extension property given by image factorization as we can define kernels using the dimension structure).

Comment: @OmerRosler Ok, so the behavior of pullbacks you describe follows just from having an ordinal-valued functor. I'm afraid I still don't see what the extension property is doing for you mathematically. But perhaps as you develop the theory you will find a use for it.